# Can't get existing table from embedded hsqldb

Tags: java, hsqldb

To use embedded database I have created hsqldb database connected with java by [this tutorial](http://www.javavillage.in/hsql-db-sample-example.php).

In general it is about creating simple table with 3 records through hsqldb manager and connect to this database with java.

Database was created and after exit the manager and connect again I gained my tables. They are recorded in *test.script* file.

If I try to connect with java by

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/db/test;ifexists=true", "SA", "");
```

then I got connection and can read all tables from it by

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, TYPE_NAME, COLUMN_SIZE, DECIMAL_DIGITS, IS_NULLABLE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'SYSTEM_%'");
```

But I can't get previous created table in manager even if script file contains that table.

This snippet of create table is placed in *test.script* file:

```
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.SALARYDETAILS(EMPID VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY,SALARY INTEGER NOT NULL,BONUS INTEGER NOT NULL,INCREMENT INTEGER NOT NULL)
```

I was confused by MEMORY command, but maybe it is not what I should to fix. After remove it manager add it there again.

**----- update 1 -----**

SHUTDOWN command didn't help.
I don't know how HSQLDB store data, but thought that when they are in script file, it is done.

Exception what is see in the command line when running Java is 
*user lacks privilege or object not found*

**----- update 2 -----**

I have created a table in Java and record data into it and I was available to get these data, but can't see it in the manager. It seems to me like different database, but location is same.

Script file doesn't contain new table and data. I don't know where data are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the database file was not saved. Before you exit the manager, execute this SQL command:

```
SHUTDOWN
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. I have put that command into the manager and run. Anyway after close and run manager I was available to get data properly without previous call of SHUTDOWN command.

Comment: I'm feeling the problem with run initialize script. Should I run it manually in Java? Or init the database engine somehow?

Comment: Make sure you are using exactly the same path for the database, both in manager and in Java.

Comment: Manager URL is `jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\java\\hsqldb\\db\\test` and I'm using in Java `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/db/test;ifexists=true;shutdown=true`. The database was created by manager and I started to use it in Java. Must exists some connection between manager and Java app? Because I'm using manager as standalone app without adding any address into the classpath.

Comment: These URLs are two different file paths. Use the Manager URL in Java app and it will work.

Comment: Well I think they are same. The Java's URL is just relative. But to be sure I copied URL from manager to Java and got this exception `unexpected token: CONFLICT required: DEADLOCK`. Application failed on the line with getting connection `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\java\\hsqldb\\db\\test", "SA", "")`. Anyway thank you for your concern.

Comment: You was right ... url's are not same. `/db/test` used in Java pointing to `C:\db\ `  folder where is `test` database.  I thought that it is relative. So I have to use absolute path instead relative and without `c:` in case to use under windows system?

Comment: Final solution is use as relative path `db/test` instead `/db/test`. Right string url connection in Java `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/test;ifexists=true;shutdown=true", "SA", "")` and right url connection in the manager is `jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\java\\hsqldb\\db\\test`. Stupid issue, thanks for discuss :-)